# no flush on my hosting in php

Tags: php, flush

my hosting site, not flushing the content...
its echoing all the content at the End.

i have tried many method for flushing it, but still not flushing..like

```
flush();
ob_flush()

ob_start();

ob_flush();
```

i found this from php.net, but still not working.

```
<?php
function flush_buffers(){
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();
ob_start();
}
?>
```

etc etc

so what's the problems ??

please check my phpinfo from here.

```
http://dotmama.tk/info.php
```

and post the solution.

Comment: Can you do the code `var_dump(function_exists('ob_start'))`? Let us know the result.

Comment: What is the content that is being flushed, it's it's not a complete renderable unit for the browser the browser will wait around until it gets enough content for it to make sense of it.

Comment: i have tried in many hosting. but stil not work. 

i guess there are some problems in php.ini

Comment: its coming bool(true) @wind

Comment: Check [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php).

Comment: that's kind of how things work by default with php, are you sure this is the right approach for the task?

Comment: please tell us the result of `var_dump(ob_end_flush())`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
<?php
   ob_start();
?>
This is the test and test and $among others.
<?php
   ob_end_flush();
?>
```

You have put some content between `ob_start` and `ob_end_flush` or it will appear as blank page in your browser.

And if you are using Google Chrome, you have to add the `Content-Type` in your header (eg: `header('Content-Type: text/plain')`). This is due to the bug of the said browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this at start:

```
apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
ini_set('output_buffering', 0);
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
```